# WSImport Not generating code for not required element

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, wsimport

I have a wsdl file while creating a client in netbeans it is not generating setter method for not required methods.

for example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"jobPackageName", "jobDefinitionName", "paramList"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "submitESSJobRequest")
public class SubmitESSJobRequest {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String jobPackageName;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String jobDefinitionName;
    protected List<String> paramList;

    public SubmitESSJobRequest() {
    }

    public String getJobPackageName() {
    }

    public void setJobPackageName(String string) {
    }

    public String getJobDefinitionName() {
    }

    public void setJobDefinitionName(String string) {

    }

    public List<String> getParamList() {
    }
}
```

here setter for paramList is not created. 
**How to set value of paramList?**

Comment: Is this the generated code?

Comment: Yes.. but it's not complete code.. complete code has 140 classes..it's just a snippet

Comment: Does the problem only occur when you generate the code in netbeans or also when you use wsimport on the console?

Comment: Its same when I execute wsimport from console also

Comment: Can you post the wsdl file?

Comment: It's local to my system. Moreover it's from client system. Hence I can't post it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146901/discussion-between-edwardth-and-sarvesh-tank).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a jaxb xjc extension library in your build classpath and use the -Xsetters xjcArg. This will cause your generated stubs to have setters for your List objects.

For Maven users with the jaxws-maven-plugin, it looks like this:

```
  <!-- generates webservice client stubs using wsimport -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxws-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/${resources-folder}/wsdl/v1</wsdlDirectory>
                    <wsdlFile>${wsdlFileName}</wsdlFile>
                    <bindingFiles>
                        <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxb-bindings.xml</bindingFile>
                    </bindingFiles>
                    <vmArgs>
                        <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg> <!-- necessary for JDK 8 -->
                    </vmArgs>
                    <xjcArgs>
                        <xjcArg>-Xsetters</xjcArg>
                    </xjcArgs>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- put xjc-plugins on the jaxws-maven-plugin's classpath -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.5</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

And for Maven users with the cxf-codegen-plugin it looks like this:

```
    <!-- generates webservice client stubs using CXF framework-->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                    <wsdlOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>${adapter.api.wsdlFileName}</wsdl>
                            <bindingFiles>
                                <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxb-bindings.xml</bindingFile>
                            </bindingFiles>
                            <extraargs>
                                <extraarg>-xjc-Xsetters</extraarg><!-- needed so that setters for lists are generated -->
                            </extraargs>
                        </wsdlOption>
                    </wsdlOptions>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- plugin needed to customize cxf genrated classes -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```